# horizontally align and adding div items horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am using following code

```
<div style="display: table; width: 50%; clear: both; ">
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; color: #000;">
            <span><?php echo $genericItem;?></span>
            <img style="margin-left: 20px; height: 50px; width: 50px;" src="<?php echo $genericItemPath;?>" alt=""> 
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: right; margin-left: 25px;">
            <span style="font-size: 20px; color: #000"><b>Reorder</b> in <?php echo $reorderDays;?> days</span>
            <span style="display: block;  font-size: 12px; color: #d3d3d3; max-width: 90%;"><?php echo $reorderDate;?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

To create something like this 
[image]

However the second reorder div is showing below but on right side. How can I modify the div.

Comment: It's probably because you have `width: 50%` but also have a `margin-left: 25px` which is making your second div exceed your screen width.

What happens if you remove the `margin-left` from the second div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps. I think that using `flex` is the best way to make columns and it is the way that works for what you want to do. In addition to that `flex` is a property that is beginning to be used by modern websites.

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

/* extra */
.column2 {background-color: #f8f8f8;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="column">Apple</div>
  <div class="column column2">
    <p><b>Re-order:</b> in 3 days</p>
    <p>Tuesday 19-9-2018</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: You can remove `justify-content` and `text-align` as well as `.column2`. I only have them so you can appreciate how the columns would look.

Answer (score 0):

You have `width: 50%` but also have a `margin-left: 25px` which is making your second div exceed your screen width.

Try removing the `margin-left` and in this case the second div should float right.
If you want to add spacing between them, increase the parent width or decrease each divs width.